# Where is best to initialize React with Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, sdk, initialization

## Setup

React app With Redux handles the state and actions.
Lots of services - User login API, google maps and several third-party services.

## Problem

Initialize is running multiple times when it's part of component (componentDidMount), SDK scripts loaded during the process (I want them to be ready when I need them in the app).

## Leading Questions

- Where and when running the `appInitialize()` function so it will run only once (at the app startup only).
- Where to load the Google API script? (In the component that uses it or in the App component?)
- Best practices, Books and other guides reference may also help.

Comment: - Hi, state of each reducer get initialize in their argument. - there is no Google API script by default. - redux bible: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question before, basically, I want to bootstrap my own app. Inside `index.js`, assuming that your goal is to render the app, you can do a lot of things before that.

`ReactDOM.render(Root, document.getElementById('root'));`

For example

- create a redux store, and inject it into this app (sync)
- call a promise, and then resolve it before calling render (async)

It's a javascript file, you can do anything you want, most of the time you can think of this as a laundry list. When you get more and more stuff, you might think a more modular way of doing it (ex. react or redux being just one of the module).

Just to answer your question

- Where and when running the `appInitialize()` function so it will run only once (at the app startup only)? Inside `index.js`, make sure you call render only once. And make sure you initialize other things all before that hopefully.
- Where to load the Google API script? (In the component that uses it or in the App component?). All third party can be either in `index.html` or `index.js`, you can just call them once and leave them there.